# ReverseGeocodingTask task to a method

Tags: java, android, geolocation

I grab a code from the android site that do the reverse geocoding (transfering a location from numbers to a text)

It's working fine but since my application has changed a bit I need to change this code into a normal method, right now it's an AsyncTask. It should get a Location and return a string.

This code is a bit strange to me so I need your help guys:

```
private class ReverseGeocodingTask extends AsyncTask<Location, Void, Void> 
{
    Context mContext;

    public ReverseGeocodingTask(Context context) 
    {
        super();
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Location... params) 
    {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(mContext, Locale.getDefault());

        Location loc = params[0];
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Update address field with the exception.
            LocationService.this.address = e.toString();
        }
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) 
        {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            // Format the first line of address (if available), city, and country name.
            String addressText = String.format("%s, %s, %s",
                    address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
                    address.getLocality(),
                    address.getCountryName());
            // Update address field on UI.
           // Message.obtain(mHandler, UPDATE_ADDRESS, addressText).sendToTarget();
            LocationService.this.address = addressText;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Reverse GeoCoding takes a significiant amount of time, you shouldn't do it on the UI thread. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: On a thread that sends the location to the db. so before I send it I would like to transfer it into a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start by making a method like so

```
public String reverseGeocode(Location loc) {


}
```

change the line that grabs the first location, being the only one used, and remove it - you already have loc

```
//Location loc = params[0];
```

Then instead of setting the address to that location service, just return it:

```
//LocationService.this.address = addressText;
return addressText;
```

Splice those into the method, remove the unnecessary return statement at the end, and you're golden.

Upon a closer look I'm also seeing an exception you'll simply want to throw up the chain instead of handling inside this method. Let that get handled by whatever calls your method on a case-by-case basis: it's not a problem this method can solve.

Comment: Thanks but what about the context?from where do I grab this instance?

Comment: Wherever you get it from presently. You still need that same context.