# How can I filter out the city-level GPS locations and use street-level locations only?

Tags: java, android, geolocation

I'm generating locations using the network and the gps providers.
Before I use them I pass them to a method called "isUsable" and if they are then I use it.

Here is the method:

```
public boolean isUsable(Location location)
{
    return location!=null && location.hasAccuracy() && location.getAccuracy() < 800;
}
```

In other words the location should be exist, with accuracy and very accurate. After testing the application a VERY not accurate location was found on my db: "Israel, Tel aviv" .

How come? A city level location can be less then 800 accuracy??

Comment: Where were you actually standing when you tested this?  In Tel Aviv?

Comment: You mean that a GPS location in Israel has deliverd an horicontal accuracy of more than 800 meters?

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes I stand in Tel Aviv, I would like to use only street level locations not city level.

Comment: @AlexWien I mean that I don't want to use this kind of locations, what's wrong in my method?how come this unaccurate location return true on my method.

Comment: Why is it not accurate if you are standing in Tel Aviv?  Use a street-level location instead of a city-level one.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm sorry I guess that I don't express my self good. When I say not accurate I mean that undetailed location. I would like ot ignore this type of locations and use the street level locations (Israel, Tel Aviv st.1-5 for example).

Comment: There is nothing wrong, the error is somewhere else.

Comment: @AlexWien Do you know where? How can I ignore this kind of "undetailed" locations?I thought that the accuracy method checks that but apparently I was wrong.

Comment: The location that you get is a coordinate. The accuracy of the coordinate is < 800 meters. Your problem is that whatever service you are using to convert your coordinate to a street address isn't good.

Comment: Sounds like we're getting progress, I'm using a piece of code from the android dev website. Here is another question started by me using this code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489714/reversegeocodingtask-task-to-a-method

Comment: So guys do you have any idea how I can do that?